# How to check if hex color is "too black"?

Tags: javascript, colors

I'm trying to evaluate the darkness of a color chosen by a color picker to see if it's "too black", and if so, set it to white. I thought I could use the first characters of the hex value to pull this off. It's working, but it's switching some legitimately "light" colors too.

I have the following code:

```js
if (lightcolor.substring(0, 3) == "#00" || lightcolor.substring(0, 3) == "#010") {
  lightcolor = "#FFFFFF";
  color = lightcolor;
}
```

There must be a more efficient way with hex math to know that a color has gone beyond a certain level of darkness? Like if `lightcolor` + "some hex value" `<=` "some hex value" then set it to `white`.

I have `tinyColor` added, which might be of use for this, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Have you tried getting up a color picker and checking the values? I noticed that when R, G and B are all under ~70 it gets dark. This might not be the proper way, but it's one.

Comment: As you're already using tinyColor, transform the color to [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and have a look at the **L** component. 1 = white, 0 = black

Comment: @Andreas HSL lightness doesn't take human perception into account. An L value of 0.5 will have a different perceived brightness for different hues.

Comment: @Alnitak You're right but the description of the TO isn't that precisely. So any value below 3/8 could have been dark enough for his purpose.

Comment: @Andreas that depends - if you look at the ITU luminance values in my answer you'll see that blue is perceived as only 1/10th as bright as green.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You have to extract the three RGB components individually, and then use a standard formula to convert the resulting RGB values into their perceived brightness.

Assuming a six character colour:

```
var c = c.substring(1);      // strip #
var rgb = parseInt(c, 16);   // convert rrggbb to decimal
var r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;  // extract red
var g = (rgb >>  8) & 0xff;  // extract green
var b = (rgb >>  0) & 0xff;  // extract blue

var luma = 0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b; // per ITU-R BT.709

if (luma < 40) {
    // pick a different colour
}
```

**EDIT**

Since May 2014 `tinycolor` now has a `getBrightness()` function, albeit using the CCIR601 weighting factors instead of the ITU-R ones above.

**EDIT**

The resulting luma value range is 0..255, where 0 is the darkest and 255 is the lightest. Values greater than 128 are considered light by `tinycolor`. (shamelessly copied from the comments by @pau.moreno and @Alnitak)

Comment: haven't seen some good bit manipulation in javascript in a while. cool stuff. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709#Luma_coefficients

Comment: Good code, but after testing I suggest var luma = (r + g + b)/3; if (luma < 128) {
    // will be more useful.
}

Comment: @TerryLin Why?  The coefficients given are the _standard_ ITU values that allow for the fact that green is _perceived_ more brightly than red (and then blue).

Comment: @Alnitak I use your code to detect dark/light background and then display white/black font color, the result is not good. But average r,g,b and luma < 128 = dark background, luma > 128 = light background, the result is what I need. Thank you very much for your code.

Comment: @TerryLin well, whatever works for you.  This worked for the OP :)

Comment: The resulting `luma` value range is `0..255`, where `0` is the darkest and `255` is the lightest (the three coefficients sum to one).

Comment: luma < 40 ? what does it mean? is it more dark? also why 40? not 125?

Comment: @MeetMahPuppy the number 40 in this case is just an example

Comment: @gabssnake only since May 2014, and the `isDark()` threshold is hard-coded at 128

Comment: @Alnitak fair enough

Comment: let [r, g, b] = elem.style.backgroundColor.match(/\d+/g);

Answer (score 61):

I found this WooCommerce Wordpress PHP function ([wc_hex_is_light](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-formatting-functions.php)) and I converted to JavaScript. Works fine!

```
function wc_hex_is_light(color) {
    const hex = color.replace('#', '');
    const c_r = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
    const c_g = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
    const c_b = parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16);
    const brightness = ((c_r * 299) + (c_g * 587) + (c_b * 114)) / 1000;
    return brightness > 155;
}
```

---

@Sliffcak, thanks for comment... To use `substring`, because `substr` was deprecated:

```
function wc_hex_is_light(color) {
    const hex = color.replace('#', '');
    const c_r = parseInt(hex.substring(0, 0 + 2), 16);
    const c_g = parseInt(hex.substring(2, 2 + 2), 16);
    const c_b = parseInt(hex.substring(4, 4 + 2), 16);
    const brightness = ((c_r * 299) + (c_g * 587) + (c_b * 114)) / 1000;
    return brightness > 155;
}
```

Comment: Super cool, thx! I tested it with several colors, detection was correct with all of them :)

Comment: colorIsDarkOrLight(color) {
      var hex = color.replace("#", "");
      var c_r,
        c_g,
        c_b,
        brightness = "";
      if (hex.length == 3) {
        c_r = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
        c_g = parseInt(hex.substr(1, 2), 16);
        c_b = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
        brightness = (c_r * 299 + c_g * 587 + c_b * 114) / 1000;
      } else {
        c_r = parseInt(hex.substr(0, 2), 16);
        c_g = parseInt(hex.substr(2, 2), 16);
        c_b = parseInt(hex.substr(4, 2), 16);
      }
      return brightness > 155;
    },

Comment: Use with hex 3 characteres and 6

Comment: This code is GPL licensed. Please don't steal without following the license rules. (I am not affiliated with this project nor am I a lawyer) https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5d7f6acbcb387f1d51d51305bf949d07fa3c4b08/license.txt

Comment: The author has always been quoted. The original source code was always linked. What did you (@jayphelps) mean by 'steal'?

Comment: @SergioCabral thanks! however substr has been deprecated. when I switched it to substring it is not working

Answer (score 38):

The [TinyColor](https://bgrins.github.io/TinyColor/) library (you've already mentioned it) provides several functions for inspecting and manipulating colors, among them:

- [getBrightness](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor#getbrightness)

  > Returns the perceived brightness of a color, from 0-255, as defined by [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (Version 1.0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/AERT#color-contrast).
  >
  > ```
  > tinycolor("#fff").getBrightness(); // 255
  > ```
- [isLight](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor#islight)

  > Return a boolean indicating whether the color's perceived brightness is light.
  >
  > ```
  > tinycolor("#fff").isLight(); // true
  > tinycolor("#000").isLight(); // false
  > ```
- [isDark](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor#isdark)

  > Return a boolean indicating whether the color's perceived brightness is dark.
  >
  > ```
  > tinycolor("#fff").isDark(); // false
  > tinycolor("#000").isDark(); // true
  > ```
- [getLuminance](https://github.com/bgrins/TinyColor#getluminance)

  > Returns the perceived luminance of a color, from 0-1 as defined by [Web Content Accessibility Guidelines (Version 2.0)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#contrast-ratiodef).
  >
  > ```
  > tinycolor("#fff").getLuminance(); // 1
  > ```

Comment: By far the easiest way, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

This work with hex e.g #fefefe

```
function isTooDark(hexcolor){
    var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(1,2),16);
    var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(3,2),16);
    var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(4,2),16);
    var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
    // Return new color if to dark, else return the original
    return (yiq < 40) ? '#2980b9' : hexcolor;
}
```

---

You can change it to return `true` or `false` by change

```
return (yiq < 40) ? '#2980b9' : hexcolor;
```

to

```
return (yiq < 40);
```

Comment: @Vivek that's because you need to use full hex values (#000000 and #ffffff)

Answer (score 6):

You can compute the [luminance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance):

> Luminance is thus an indicator of how bright the surface will appear.

So it's great to choose if the text should be white or black.

```
var getRGB = function(b){
    var a;
    if(b&&b.constructor==Array&&b.length==3)return b;
    if(a=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(b))return[parseInt(a[1]),parseInt(a[2]),parseInt(a[3])];
    if(a=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(b))return[parseFloat(a[1])*2.55,parseFloat(a[2])*2.55,parseFloat(a[3])*2.55];
    if(a=/#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(b))return[parseInt(a[1],16),parseInt(a[2],16),parseInt(a[3],
16)];
    if(a=/#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(b))return[parseInt(a[1]+a[1],16),parseInt(a[2]+a[2],16),parseInt(a[3]+a[3],16)];
    return (typeof (colors) != "undefined")?colors[jQuery.trim(b).toLowerCase()]:null
};

var luminance_get = function(color) {
    var rgb = getRGB(color);
    if (!rgb) return null;
        return 0.2126 * rgb[0] + 0.7152 * rgb[1] + 0.0722 * rgb[2];
}
```

The method above allows you to pass the color in different formats, but the algorithm is basically just in `luminance_get`.

When I used it, I was setting the color to black if the luminance was greater than `180`, white otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

There's an important distinction here between luminance and brightness. Luminance, at the end of the day, is a measure of how much energy travels through a certain area and completely ignores how our perceptual systems perceive that energy. Brightness, on the other hand, is a measure of how we perceive that energy and takes into the account the relationship between luminance and our perceptual system. (As a point of confusion, there is a term called relative luminance, which seems to be used synonymously with brightness terms. It tripped me up good).

To be precise, you are looking for "brightness" or "value" or "relatively luminance" as others have suggested. You can calculate this in several different way (such is to be human!) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness

1. Take the max of R, G, and B.
2. Take the average of the max and the min from R, G, and B.
3. Take the average of all three.
4. Use some weighted average as others have suggested here.

Comment: AFAIK only the _luma_ calculation described on the Wikipedia page is a perception-based model.

Comment: It's nice to point out the distinction between physical light energy and perceived brightness, but I think you've got things rather mixed up.  The section of the Wikipedia article you linked to has a fourth bullet point, which states "A *more perceptually relevant* alternative is to use luma, Y′, as a lightness dimension" (emphasis mine) and then proceeds to give the formula presented in Alnitak's and Robin's answers.  In other words, the method you've left out and recommended against is the one which best matches human perception.

Comment: @JohnY yes, that's what I was trying to say - he's left out the only one which actually matches the rest of his answer.

Comment: Yes, turns out I was the only one confused here. I'm okay with that :) I just wanted to get the major point across that there is a different between energy and perception. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this conversation is a few years old, but it is still relevant.  I wanted to add that my team was having the same issue in Java (SWT) and found this to be a bit more accurate:

```
private Color getFontColor(RGB bgColor) {
    Color COLOR_BLACK = new Color(Display.getDefault(), 0, 0, 0);
    Color COLOR_WHITE = new Color(Display.getDefault(), 255, 255, 255);

    double luminance = Math.sqrt(0.241 
       * Math.pow(bgColor.red, 2) + 0.691 * Math.pow(bgColor.green, 2) +  0.068 
       * Math.pow(bgColor.blue, 2));
    if (luminance >= 130) {
        return COLOR_BLACK;
    } else {
        return COLOR_WHITE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to convert your color [from RGB to HSB](https://github.com/mjackson/mjijackson.github.com/blob/03ac0138b971a8e0f11e7edc110171508587ddd5/2008/02/rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-conversion-algorithms-in-javascript.txt). HSB stands for hue, saturation, and brightness (also known as HSV, where V is for value). Then you have just one parameter to check: brightness.

Answer (score 2):

I combined the answers of @Alnitak and @SergioCabral below. I also implemented a hex value parser that works for standard and short forms.

```js
const hexToRgb = (hex) =>
  (value =>
    value.length === 3
      ? value.split('').map(c => parseInt(c.repeat(2), 16))
      : value.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(v => parseInt(v, 16)))
  (hex.replace('#', ''));

// Luma - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043228/1762224
const isHexTooDark = (hexColor) =>
  (([r, g, b]) =>
    (0.2126 * r + 0.7152 * g + 0.0722 * b) < 40)
  (hexToRgb(hexColor));

// Brightness - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51567564/1762224
const isHexTooLight = (hexColor) =>
  (([r, g, b]) =>
    (((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000) > 155)
  (hexToRgb(hexColor));

console.log(isHexTooDark('#222'));  // true
console.log(isHexTooLight('#DDD')); // true
```