# c# or Java-script - How to measure color visibility when placed on another color

Tags: javascript, c#

I have an web application where I have multiple `<li>` items that are generated dynamically.

I have need to pick a random background color and assign for each unique value in the list.

I am picking color using this function:

```
function GenerateRandomColor()
{
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}
```

**Problem:** For few colors text is not visible because background color is too dark.

**Is there any method to check if text color will be visible on the generated random color?**

I am using c# on server side so I can pick color using c# or Java-script. So any solution will be helpful for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if hex color is "too black"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043187/how-to-check-if-hex-color-is-too-black)

Comment: The question [How to check if hex color is "too black" ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043187/how-to-check-if-hex-color-is-too-black) might have the answer you need.

Comment: OOPS. Its a duplicate. Searched with wrong key words. Thanks for the links

Comment: Also, see [Color.GetHue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.gethue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Color.GetBrightness()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness(v=vs.110).aspx). Using the Hue value, is quite simple to find a result. Hue is expressed in degrees (0-360).

Comment: In your case I think it would have sufficed to remove "012345" from the letters :)