# How to avoid generating too black colors at random in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random, colors, rgb

Whenever I click a button on the browser it displays a random color along with its rgb(r,g,b) code. I made 3 variables `r`, `g`, and `b` which produce random numbers from `0` to `255` using the basic logic of `Math.floor(Math.random()*256)`;

My problem is that sometimes the random colors generated are too dark and the rgb code displayed along with them is black in color.

I tried writing a logic that whenever r+g+b < 300, toggle the h1 element's class which has a property of color white.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const button = document.querySelector("button");
h1.classList.add('h1');
//if (r+g+b < 500)
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    changeColor();
});

const changeColor = (() => {
    const newColor = randomColor();
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
    h1.innerText = newColor;
    }
);

const randomColor = (() => {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if hex color is "too black"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043187/how-to-check-if-hex-color-is-too-black)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to make the r, g, b variables have a wider scope so they can be used to do your <500 test in the same place that you change the background color.

```js
const h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let r, g, b;
h1.classList.add('h1');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeColor();
});

const changeColor = (() => {
  const newColor = randomColor();
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor;
  if (r + g + b < 500) h1.style.color = 'white';
  else h1.style.color = 'black';
  h1.innerText = newColor;
});

const randomColor = (() => {
  r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
})
```

```html
<h1></h1>
<button>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```html
  const changeColor = (() => {
        const newColor = randomColor();

        document.body.style.backgroundColor = newColor[1];
        h1.innerText = newColor[1];

       const sumColor = newColor[0];

        if (sumColor < 300){
            h1.style.color = white;
        }else{
            h1.style.color = black;

        }



    }
    );

    const randomColor = (() => {
        const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
        const sum = r+g+b;
        return [sum,`rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`]; //returning array
        
 
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to put your if inside this function (randomColor ) and when the values are generated for (r,g,b) you're if for the new values will be checked again every time the values change.

```
const randomColor = (() => {
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    if(r+g+b < 300){
      h1.classList.add('h1');
    }
    return `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
})
```

Comment: Then, the `randomColor` logic and the class add logic would be intermingled, which should be avoided. Rather, the `if` condition should be outside of `randomColor` and dependent on its return value.