Status Bar incorrectly displays time and other status colors in API 35 Android Emulators
I am currently trying to migrate my app to be compatible with Android 15. And as far as I concerned, in order to test Android 15 API, we need set up API 35 or VanillaIceCream API. Also based on the Android 15 migration, my app is set to edge-to-edge by default (which I don't want to).
After spending time to config the app, I manage to set the app to display correctly on my VanillaIceCream API emulator, make it display the status bar.

However, run the app in API 35 Emulator, I get this instead:

Basically the status bar items, such as time, WiFi, and battery indicator blend into the white background.
CompileSDK and targetSDK are all set to 35 in app's build.gradle.kts. And in my MainActivity.kt, i implemented the insets as follow:
My_App_Theme(
    darkTheme = darkTheme
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(
            insets = WindowInsets.systemBars
        ),
        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
    ) {
        MY_APP(
            darkTheme = darkTheme,
            onThemeUpdated = { darkTheme = !darkTheme }
        )
    }
}

Is this the emulator error due to the fact that Android 15 hasn't been out yet, or there is something wrong of how I implemented the insets for the edge-to-edge configuration?

I am having the same issue, but with view-based layouts. Not sure whether the solutions will be the same between view-based and Compose or not.

You can change the color of the status bar icons using WindowInsetsControllerCompat((context as Activity).window, context.window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars.
Example
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat((context as Activity).window, context.window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = true //false for black
}


My current solutions is change my theme.xml parent into android:Theme.Material.NoActionBar, which basically does the same thing as you said. However, what I want is not just a pre-defined color like black or white for the status bar, I want it to change color based on the Material Theme like before.

@vinhDev3006 that's no longer possible when targeting SDK 35. Check the docs: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/behavior-changes-15 (search for statusBarColor)

I am using the view system equivalent of this. Somehow it only works until i switch the ui mode (dark/light). After that setting isAppearanceLightStatusBars to any value has no effect anymore.

I feel like this is a terrible change, but according to the official documentation:

If your app must offer custom background protection to 3-button navigation or the status bar, your app should place a composable or view behind the system bar using WindowInsets.Type#tappableElement() to get the 3-button navigation bar height or WindowInsets.Type#statusBars.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/15/behavior-changes-15
This makes it sound like you only need to do this if you need your app to interact with the status bar or navigation bar, but it's the only way I could find to color them.
There's probably an easier way but until someone else comes by with a better answer, here's what I did:
val statusBarColor = Color.Black
val navBarColor = Color.Black

// Set the icon/text colors in the status bar and nav bar
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !statusBarColor.isDark()
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = !navBarColor.isDark()

Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.width(
            WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues().calculateStartPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr)
        ).background(navBarColor).fillMaxHeight()
    )
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f, false),) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.height(
                WindowInsets.statusBars.asPaddingValues().calculateTopPadding()
            ).background(statusBarColor).fillMaxWidth()
        )
        MainComposable(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().weight(1f, false))
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier.height(
                WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues().calculateBottomPadding()
            ).background(navBarColor).fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.width(
            WindowInsets.navigationBars.asPaddingValues().calculateEndPadding(LayoutDirection.Ltr)
        ).background(navBarColor).fillMaxHeight()
    )
}

In this code, MainComposable is whatever you are using to display your app's main content. The modifier on it is necessary to make sure that the navigation bar coloring remains at the bottom of the screen when the navigation bar is down there.
This colors the status bar statusBarColor and the navigation bar navBarColor. Notice that it also accounts for the navigation bar rotating with the screen when the device is rotated. This also works with both the 3-button navigation, and gesture based navigation.
Also, my isDark function looks like this:
/**
 * Decides if a color is dark or light. Dark colors should have light (white) text displayed on them
 * and vice versa.
 *
 * @return True if the color is dark, otherwise false
 */
fun Color.isDark() : Boolean {
    // Extract individual colors. * 255 because they're returned as a fractional value
    val r = red * 255
    val g = green * 255
    val b = blue * 255

    // Code converted from here: (not the accepted answer)
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043187/how-to-check-if-hex-color-is-too-black

    val brightness = ((r * 0.2126) + (g * .7152) + (b * .0722)) * alpha

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1497116/how-to-find-if-a-given-color-is-dark-or-light
    return brightness < 128
}

I also added enableEdgeToEdge() in my activity's onCreate function, so that it would be consistent across OS versions. (Without this, things will look different on API 35 vs older API levels, unless you adjust for that elsewhere.)
I also had to do some other adjustments, including not using the padding variable in any Scaffold objects. (That padding is the screen's padding for things like the status bar and navigation bar, which we are now accounting for ourselves.)
